# getting all addresses for active lenders in aave v3

Tags: web3.py, python, infura, aave, avalanche

specifically right now im looking at avax liquidity pool, heres what i've tried so far from using the avax address in https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/v3-mainnet/avalanche:

```
from web3 import Web3
import json

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('https://avalanche-mainnet.infura.io/v3/ea257c975a7f452d9a30c12867d3b0e4'))
contract_address = '0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7'
contract_abi = json.loads('i put the abi for wavax from the aave docs here')
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=contract_address, abi=contract_abi)

# Define the block range
start_block = 1
end_block = 39684048

# Query Deposit and Withdrawal Events
deposit_filter = contract.events.Deposit.create_filter(fromBlock=start_block, toBlock=end_block)
withdraw_filter = contract.events.Withdraw.create_filter(fromBlock=start_block, toBlock=end_block)

deposits = deposit_filter.get_all_entries()
withdrawals = withdraw_filter.get_all_entries()

# Track Net Balances
balances = {}
for event in deposits:
    if event.args.reserve == web3.to_checksum_address('0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7'):  # AVAX token address
        user = event.args.user
        amount = event.args.amount
        balances[user] = balances.get(user, 0) + amount

for event in withdrawals:
    if event.args.reserve == web3.to_checksum_address('0xB31f66AA3C1e785363F0875A1B74E27b85FD66c7'):  # AVAX token address
        user = event.args.user
        amount = event.args.amount
        balances[user] = balances.get(user, 0) - amount

# Filter for Positive Balances (Active Deposits) and Print
for user, balance in balances.items():
    if balance > 0:
        print(f"User: {user}, Active Deposit Balance: {balance}")
```

Comment: Hi! Can you tell us what isn't working?